# Soql query that pulls Contacts from a custom Account Lookup field

Tags: soql

We have a custom field on Opportunities called "Referring Account", which is a lookup field related to Accounts. Is it possible to run a query on Opportunities that pulls in every Contact associated to the Account in this custom lookup field (Referring Account) and if so, how would you go about writing it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The rule is you can only go "up" five relationships and "down" one, with other patterns like "up one, then down one" being disallowed (which is essentially what you're asking for). The solution to this would be to query the accounts directly, which renders a query a bit like the following:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT Name FROM Contacts),
  (SELECT Name FROM Referred_Opportunities__r)
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Referring_Account__c FROM Opportunity) AND
      Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact)
```

Where the first two sub-queries will return lists of contacts and opportunities that were referred to the account (check the "child relationship name" `Referred_Opportunities__r` in your Referring Account field to determine the correct relationship name to use), and the third and fourth sub-queries simply limits the query to only accounts which have at least one opportunity and contact (feel free to adjust as necessary).